# создать функцию добавления элемента на страницу

Tags: javascript, функции, инспекция-кода

Необходимо создать функцию добавления элементов на страницу для такого кода:

```
// var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
// wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
// var parentWrapper = document.querySelector('body');
// parentWrapper.insertBefore(wrapper, parentWrapper.children[0]);

// var header1 = document.createElement('h1');
// header1.classList.add('header1');
// var parentHeader1 = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
// parentHeader1.insertBefore(header1, parentHeader1.children[0]);
```

У меня получилось вот так:

```
function createElement(tagName, className, parentTagOrClass, varName, parentVarName, childPosition){
    window[varName] = document.createElement(tagName);
    window[varName].classList.add(className);
    window[parentVarName] = document.querySelector(parentTagOrClass);
    window[parentVarName].insertBefore(window[varName], window[parentVarName].children[childPosition]); 
};
createElement('div', 'wrapper', 'body', 'wrapper', 'parentWrapper', 0);
createElement('h1', 'header1', '.wrapper', 'header1', 'parentHeader1', 0);
```

Но, как я понимаю, это плохое решение, из-за создания глобальных переменных. Подскажите как сделать правильно?

Comment: Каких глобальных переменных?

Comment: window[varName], window[parentVarName], которые доступны за пределами функции, или я что-то неправильно понимаю?

Comment: а зачем использовать глобальные переменные?

Comment: к тому же данный код не работает, если в контейнере еще нет элементов

Comment: Grundy,  эта функция нужна для того чтобы не писать "простыню" кода, а добавлять элементы с помощью вызова функции с новыми параметрами. Т.е. createElement('div', 'wrapper', 'body', 'wrapper', 'parentWrapper', 0); createElement('h1', 'header1', '.wrapper', 'wrapper', 'parentHeader1', 0); и т.д.

Comment: а без глобальных переменных я не знаю как это сделать, поэтому и задал этот вопрос

Comment: код работает - создает div с классом wrapper в тэге <body>

Comment: попробуйте выполнить его когда в body не будет ни одного элемента

Comment: а не :) это я пробовал неправильно :)

Comment: :) так как обойти эти глобальные переменные, может как-то через объекты попробовать?

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего было взять исходный код

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
var parentWrapper = document.querySelector('body');
parentWrapper.insertBefore(wrapper, parentWrapper.children[0]);
```

и обернуть его в функцию

```
function create(){
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
    var parentWrapper = document.querySelector('body');
    parentWrapper.insertBefore(wrapper, parentWrapper.children[0]);
}
```

Осталось только взять то, что может поменяться, в данном случае это: 'div', 'wrapper', 'body', 0, и сделать параметрами

```
function create(tagName, className, container, index){
    var wrapper = document.createElement(tagName);
    wrapper.classList.add(className);
    var parentWrapper = document.querySelector(container);
    parentWrapper.insertBefore(wrapper, parentWrapper.children[index]);
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.